# passing the result of a command to SED

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, command

I want do to the following, get the host ip of my server and then use this value to substitute a dummy value in a config file.

For step 1 to get the server ip I call:

```
hostname -I | head -n1 | awk '{print $1;}'
```

For step 2 to replace the dummy value in the file I would do:

```
sed -i 's/dummyvalue/valuefromprevioushostnamecommand/g' filename.
```

The idea is to combine this steps into one unix command without using any shell scripting.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated
Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there - just nest the two commands within each other:

```
sed -i s/'dummyvalue'/$(hostname -I | head -n1 | awk '{print $1;}')/g filename
```

Note that you need to remove the surrounding single-quotes around the `s///g`, and placed them around the `dummyvalue` instead. Otherwise bash won't try to interpret the inner command.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  let me give that a shot.

Comment: worked like a charm, why can't I accept your answer?

Comment: That will fail in weird and wonderful ways if the output of that hostname chain of commands contains any characters that mean something in the sed replacement context, e.g. `/`, `&`, `\1`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a chain of piped commands when you are using awk. Just do it in one awk command. You didn't show any sample input and expected output so this is obviously untested but will be close to what you need if not exactly:

```
hostname -I |
awk -i inplace 'NR==FNR{if (FNR==1) val=$1; nextfile} {gsub(/dummyvalue/,val)} 1' - filename
```

The above uses gawk 4.* for `-i inplace` and `nextfile`, with other awks just do:

```
hostname -I |
awk 'NR==FNR{if (FNR==1) val=$1; next} {gsub(/dummyvalue/,val)} 1' - filename > tmp && mv tmp filename
```